# webpack bunding a lot more than it should

Tags: javascript, build, webpack

Fairly simply configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index',
    resolve: {
      alias: aliases,
      extensions: ['', '.js']
    },

    output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'output.js'
    }
};
```

Running webpack errors and tries to require images and other files I'm not using or "requiring" anywhere.

When I run `webpack --profile --json` to look at dep tree, I find some weird expressions

```
 37           "id": 62,
 36           "identifier": "/Users/pyramation/web/assets/js/libs/jsfileImNotRequiring.js",
 35           "name": "./assets/js/libs/jsfileImNotRequiring.js",
 34           "index": 62,
 33           "index2": 53,
 32           "size": 11225,
 31           "cacheable": true,
 30           "built": true,
 29           "optional": true,
 28           "prefetched": false,
 27           "chunks": [
 26             0
 25           ],
 24           "assets": [],
 23           "issuer": "/Users/pyramation/web/assets/js/libs /^\\.\\/.*$/",
 22           "profile": {
 21             "factory": 22,
 20             "building": 69
 19           },
 18           "failed": false,
 17           "errors": 0,
 16           "warnings": 0,
 15           "reasons": [
 14             {
 13               "moduleId": 61,                                             
 12               "moduleIdentifier": "/Users/pyramation/web/assets/js/libs /^\\.\\/.*$/",
 11               "module": "./assets/js/libs ^\\.\\/.*$",
 10               "moduleName": "./assets/js/libs ^\\.\\/.*$",
  9               "type": "context element",
  8               "userRequest": "./jsfileImNotRequiring.js"
  7             },
  6             {                                                                                               5               "moduleId": 61,
  4               "moduleIdentifier": "/Users/pyramation/web/assets/js/libs /^\\.\\/.*$/",
  3               "module": "./assets/js/libs ^\\.\\/.*$",
  2               "moduleName": "./assets/js/libs ^\\.\\/.*$",
  1               "type": "context element",
  0               "userRequest": "./jsfileImNotRequiring"
  1             }
  2           ],
```

Looks like there is an expression `/^\\.\\/.*$/` appended to the libs folder, which I'm not explicitly globbing or anything like that, so not sure where this comes from.

Any light on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack starts tracing dependencies from your entry file. As it traces outwards deeper into your dependency tree, if webpack comes across a dynamic require, it automatically creates something called a context:

http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#automatically-created-contexts-defaults-module-xxxcontextxxx

Basically, assuming you use paths, webpack doesn't know which of the sub directory files you will be dynamically requiring, and creates a context. The context sucks up all of the files in that sub directory, because it doesn't know which files you actually will require at run time.

If you know that your dynamic requires will resolve anyway, e.g. from an alias, you could just turn off the auto create context with something like:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index',
    resolve: {
      alias: aliases,
      extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {

        unknownContextRegExp: /$^/,
        unknownContextCritical: false,

        exprContextRegExp: /$^/,
        exprContextCritical: false
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'output.js'
    }
};
```

There might be a way to limit the sub files sucked up during auto context creation, but I'm not sure: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#automatically-created-contexts-defaults-module-xxxcontextxxx

Answer (score 0):

after much debugging, it was `pusher`

https://github.com/DanielApt/webpack-pusher

Comment: Did you manage to make pusher somehow smaller in the final js bundle?